# Python: How do I print a string that contains multiple words on different lines?

Tags: python, string

So say I have

```
x = "this string"
```

I'm trying to print the two words on different lines. I'm thinking that I need to use `string.split()` in some way but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
print '\n'.join(x.split())
```

where

```
x = 'this string'
x.split() # ['this', 'string']
```

Comment: In the class I'm taking we're not allowed to use anything we haven't been shown and we haven't been shown join. I'm pretty much limited to the basic string functions.

Comment: @user2240033 - show `join` to the others. Or use any other answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to use `split()`. This should do it.

```
print x.replace(' ', '\n')
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/ntP20Fe8).

It replaces the space character with the newline character.

Answer (score 2):

```
x="this string"
for a in x.split():
    print a
```